# SDL2 application occasionally refuses to close

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl2

I've been working on a sliding puzzle/game of fifteen clone in SDL recently. A problem I've had is that when I close the game the app isn't always removed from the dock and I can't force quit it. It shows up in task manager, but doesn't show up in Activity Monitor so I can't quit the game from there and end up having to hard reboot.

I can't find any pattern as to why it happens some times and not others. I thought there might be something wrong with my cleanup of SDL but I can't find any problems, although I'm honestly not sure what to look for. [The full source code for this project can be found here.](https://github.com/LouiseBC/Slider-game) Thank you

Comment: Please extract the relevant pieces of code into the question body. That'll show that you've yourself done some work here as you've cut the code down to the related methods/pieces of code. Also, as it is, this question won't provide any future value if the link dies.

Answer (score 2):

In your Graphics.cpp file you have the following destructor implemented:

```
void Graphics::destroy() {
    window     = NULL;
    renderer   = NULL;
    tilenumber = NULL;
    clicks     = NULL;
    wintext    = NULL;
    menutext   = NULL;
    menuinstr  = NULL;
    cat        = NULL;
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

The issue here is that you null out `renderer` and `window` before destroying them. You are essentially trying to destory two null-pointers here, which likely results in nothing getting destroyed.

So, instead move the destroy calls to the top of the destructor. In any case, nulling out pointers isn't in any way required and seems a little redurant to me.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a try. I was taught that nulling out pointers is good practice so you don't get memory leak. Is this incorrect then?

Comment: Nulling pointers out has nothing to do with memory leaks. If you allocate memory, the only way to prevent memory leaks is to use `delete` on them.

Comment: @AdamSmith you should null out pointer only when you either have deleted it or initialized(if not initialized with anything valuable), so you can check when pointer is not pointing anywhere. Also, deleting NULL pointer is OK, but deleting pointer twice without setting it to NULL may crash your application.